# How to get the data from the Json file in the following Code

Tags: java, json

I am new to json so please help me to get solve this

```
propertyAlerts: [
{
    alertDomain: "oiq.core.alert.PropertyAlert",
    alertType: "HERITAGE_DETECTED",
    oiqCreatedDate: "2013-11-04 03:06:26"
}]
```

By using java, I want to get the following data

```
OUTPUT:
alertDomain: "oiq.core.alert.PropertyAlert"
alertType: "HERITAGE_DETECTED"
oiqCreatedDate: "2013-11-04 03:06:26"
```

The following is used by me

```
public void checklicense(String filename) throws Exception
    {
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("./output_profiles/"+filename));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray jsonMainArr = obj.getJSONArray("propertyalert"); 
JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);
     String alertDomain = childJSONObject.getString("alertDomain");

}
```

Can any one help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) tutorial explains the basics of JSON parsing.

I would recommend you to read the entire post as it is something that you will do almost daily in Android development.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void checklicense(String filename) 
{
    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filename));
        System.out.println(obj.getClass());
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray jsonMainArr = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("propertyAlerts");
        Iterator iterator = jsonMainArr.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            jsonObject =(JSONObject) iterator.next();
            String alertDomain = (String) jsonObject.get("alertDomain");
            String alertType = (String) jsonObject.get("alertType");
            System.out.println("alertDomain " + alertDomain + ", alertType " + alertType );
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EosClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

The above code produces the required output for a valid json input

```
{
"propertyAlerts": [
    {
        "alertDomain": "oiq.core.alert.PropertyAlert",
        "alertType": "HERITAGE_DETECTED",
        "oiqCreatedDate": "2013-11-04 03:06:26"
    }
]
}
```